# Can I use the child selector for the media query?

Tags: css, css-selectors, media-queries, parent-child

I have some media queries in a class and they're working absolutely fine, but the Chrome browser displays it wrongly as the only browser. So I used a browser hack for the other classes but I don't know how to target the media query. I tried this inside the browser hack:

```
.firstclass > h1 > @media(min-width: 1620px) {
      font-size: 3.7vw;
}
```

But my code editor says that `"media definitions require block statements after any features"`, so it seems that it takes it as a new media query...

How can I target it correctly? Isn't the media query a child of the class?

Comment: no afaik you cant use media query as child but use that css under that media query.

Comment: okay how do you mean that? so I should not even target the media query?

Comment: off topic, but try to not be over specific with `>`, write it rather `.firstclass h1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (min-width: 1620px) {
  .firstclass > h1{
    font-size: 3.7vw;
  }
}
```

Its a syntax error, hope it will help.

Comment: I only forgot the space here in the example, but thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 0):

Raw CSS does not allow media queries to be contained within a selector. Media queries themselves must contain the selectors they wish to apply additional styling to.

Your `.first-class > h1` declaration must be contained *within* the `@media` query block:

```
@media ... {
  .first-class > h1 > ... {
    font-size: 3.7vw;
  }
}
```

You'll need to specify what `...` is here. If you wish to target anything contained within a `h1` element, you can use the universal selector (`*`) as `.first-class > h1 > *`.

Media queries themselves target groups of selectors. Selectors do not target media queries; based on your comments here, I believe that's where you're misunderstanding how they can be used.

Comment: thank you very much for your help! 
the thing is that I have inside the h1 element 3 different media queries and I only want to target one of them to change only this ones font-size. I don't want to change the other media queries font sizes. How can I change specifially this one?

Comment: @C.Hefti this doesn't sound like raw CSS. You cannot have a media query within a selector. In raw CSS, you'd have individual `h1 { ... }` selectors within your three different `@media` queries. `@media ... { h1 { ... } } @media ... { h1 { ... } }` ...